# Google Adwords API Unauthorized CREATE operation

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-ads-api, google-docs-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using google adwords api to create campaigns and ads. I keep getting this error :Unauthorized CREATE operation in invoking a service's mutate method.
I'm using a manager account. I tried with a test account and it was working but with my manager account it doesnt.
PS : My developer token has a basic access.

```
 const client = new GoogleAdsApi({
  client_id: req.headers["client_id"],
  client_secret: req.headers["client_secret"],
  developer_token: req.headers["developer_token"],
});
const customer = client.Customer({
  customer_id: req.headers["customer_id"],
  refresh_token: req.headers["refresh_token"],
});


  const ad_group_ad = [
    {
      ad: {
        responsive_display_ad: {
          accent_color: req.body.pubGads.couleurs_perso,
          main_color: req.body.pubGads.couleurs_perso,
          marketing_images: marketing_images_tab.map((element) => {
            return {
              asset: element,
            };
          }),
          square_logo_images: square_logo_images_tab.map((element) => {
            return {
              asset: element,
            };
          }),
          square_marketing_images: square_marketing_images_tab.map(
            (element) => {
              return {
                asset: element,
              };
            }
          ),
          headlines: headlinesTab.map((element) => {
            return {
              text: element,
            };
          }),
          long_headline: {
            text: req.body.pubGads.titre_long,
          },
          descriptions: descriptionsTab.map((element) => {
            return {
              text: element,
            };
          }),
          business_name: req.body.pubGads.nom_entreprise,
          call_to_action_text: req.body.pubGads.texte_incitation,
        },
        final_urls: req.body.pubGads.url_finale.split(","),
      },
      ad_group: adGroupResults.results[0].resource_name,
      status: enums.AdGroupAdStatus.PAUSED,
    },
  ];
  const ad_group_ad_result = await customer.adGroupAds.create(ad_group_ad);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Okay I added my code for creating ads, I didn't add any at first cause I don't think it"s a code problem as it works with my testing account, but not with the real one. .3..

Comment: Whats customer?  how is that created?  remember it needs to be authorized to access the data you want to access. It sounds like you don't have access to the other account.

Comment: I updated my code, I was working with a test account and the api was working fine but when switched to manager and real account that has a token with basic acess I got that error